# Adempiere Performance Tuning Both on Application level and Database level

Tags: performance, adempiere

we had implemented Adempiere 370 in our organization itself. Its almost 2 years now. And the application is little slow now. As part of performance tuning what all things I can do with application level and database level?

Can I remove the data in the tables like AD_Issue, AD_Changelog, AD_Note, ad_wf_eventaudit, ad_wf_activity, ad_session, AD_PInstance_Log?
These temp tables can also include in data removal list: t_report, t_aging, t_trialbalance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need check this link there are information about your question. http://www.adempiere.net/en/web/guest/forums#!/thread/53516

Comment: If posting a link to an external article or answer, try and quote the most important parts here on StackOverflow - links can go down and in that case a reader coming along will have no idea what your answer is about.